# Running Total of Calculated And Rounded Variable in XSLT

Tags: xml, variables, xslt-1.0, cumulative-sum

I am trying to keep a running total of a calculated value (10% of my income, rounded up to the nearest 10 cents) in my XSLT 1.0 stylesheet, but a rounding error is giving me inaccurate results.  I know my current code is wrong, but I do not know how to correct it.

I have tried the sum using this:

`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(ceiling(sum(./bsk:Date/@income) div 10), '$#.00')" />`

This introduces the rounding errors I mentioned.

I have tried the sum using these:

`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ceiling(./bsk:Date/@income div 10)), '$#.00')" />`

`<xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(ceiling(./bsk:Date/@income div 10)), '$#.00')" /></td>`

I received the error:  "Error during XSLT transformation: An XPath expression was expected to return a NodeSet."

Below is the code I am working with.

```
<!--   The XML:  -->

<Month name="June">
    <Date num="28" day="Friday">
        <Expense amount="62.50" for="Business License" />
    </Date>
    <Date num="29" day="Saturday" income="61.30"  tithe="paid" />
    <Date num="30" day="Sunday" income="108.45" />
</Month>

<!--  The XSLT -->

<xsl:for-each select="./bsk:Month"><table>
    <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="./bsk:Date">
            <xsl:variable name="income"><xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@income"><xsl:value-of select="@income" /></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="tithe" select="ceiling($income) div 10" />
            <xsl:variable name="expenses"><xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./bsk:Expense"><xsl:value-of select="sum(./bsk:Expense/@amount)" /></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose></xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="rowspan"><xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(./bsk:Expense) &gt; 1"><xsl:value-of select="count(./bsk:Expense)" /></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="1" /></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose></xsl:variable>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="$rowspan" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@income">
                            <xsl:text>$</xsl:text>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$income" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">null</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="$rowspan" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@income">
                            <xsl:if test="@tithe='paid'"><xsl:attribute name="class">tithe_paid</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
                            <xsl:value-of select="format-number($tithe, '$#.00')" />
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:attribute name="class">null</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </td>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="./bsk:Expense">
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="./bsk:Expense/@for" /></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(./bsk:Expense[1]/@amount, '$#.00')" /></td>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise><td colspan="2" class="null"> - </td></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <td>
                    <xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="$rowspan" /></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:if test="($income - $expenses) &lt; 0"><xsl:attribute name="class">hole</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($income - $expenses - $tithe, '$#.00')" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="./bsk:Expense[position() &gt; 1]">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="@for" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="format-number(@amount, '$#.00')" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tbody>
        <tfoot><tr>
        <th>Totals</th>
        <td headers="Income"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(./bsk:Date/@income), '$#.00')" /></td>
        <td headers="Tithe"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(ceiling(sum(./bsk:Date/@income) div 10), '$#.00')" /></td>
        <td colspan="2" headers="Exp_Amount"><xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(./bsk:Date/bsk:Expense/@amount), '$#.00')" /></td>
        <td headers="Exp_Net">
            <xsl:if test="(sum(./bsk:Date/@income) - sum(./bsk:Date/bsk:Expense/@amount)) &lt; 0"><xsl:attribute name="class">hole</xsl:attribute></xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum(./bsk:Date/@income) - sum(./bsk:Date/bsk:Expense/@amount), '$#.00')" />
        </td>
    </tr></tfoot>    
</table></xsl:for-each>
```

The tithe for the Month of June is $6.20 and $10.90, which should add up to $17.10.  But since my gross income for that month was 169.75, it's being rounded to just $17.00.  Thus, my Net, which should be $90.15 is being displayed as $90.25, ten cents too high.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 cannot sum calculated values. If you want the sum of rounded values, you will need to do this in two passes: first, calculate the rounded amounts and store them in a variable, then sum the amounts stored in the variable. Or use a recursive template to accumulate the rounded amount (this would be the method to use of you really wanted a running total - I am not sure I see that in your code).

Comment: On your suggestion that I calculate the rounded amounts and store them in a variable:  I do have the following:

    <xsl:variable name="tithe" select="ceiling($income) div 10" />

How would I then sum the amounts in this variable?

Also, perhaps running total is the wrong term here.  Monthly Total would have been better.  My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <entry date="2019-07-01" amount="61.30"/>
    <entry date="2019-07-02" amount="108.45"/>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0 (+ EXSLT node-set())**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- first pass -->
<xsl:template match="/input" >
    <!-- first pass -->
    <xsl:variable name="pre-process-entries">
        <xsl:for-each select="entry">
            <entry date="{@date}" amount="{@amount}" tithe="{ceiling(@amount) div 10}"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="entries" select="exsl:node-set($pre-process-entries)/entry"/>
    <!-- output -->
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Tithe</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="$entries">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@amount, '$#.00')"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(@tithe, '$#.00')"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <tr>
            <th>TOTAL</th>
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($entries/@amount), '$#.00')"/>
            </th>
            <th>
                <xsl:value-of select="format-number(sum($entries/@tithe), '$#.00')"/>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Tithe</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-07-01</td>
    <td>$61.30</td>
    <td>$6.20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2019-07-02</td>
    <td>$108.45</td>
    <td>$10.90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
    <th>$169.75</th>
    <th>$17.10</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Rendered**

[image]

Comment: Thus far, thank you.  :)  This is working okay--but only up to a point.  I have a date where I had expenses, yet did not busk.  I didn't have an "income" attribute for that, so I had to add one with a value of 0.  Is there a way of handling when an attribute may not be there?  Second, you'll notice I have <Expense> child elements of my Date elements.  I had to put the XML file into a variable and reference THAT to list the expenses.  Is there a way of cloning those <Expense> nodes into the $pre-process-entries variable, or is what I did the only way?

Comment: There are several ways to handle the problem of no income in the input. For example, you could add an attribute with the value of 0 conditionally, using `xsl:if`. I am afraid I did not understand the other issue, and it sounds like it deserves a separate question.

Comment: I used a Choose/When/Otherwise setup for the issue of no income, setting both Income and Tithe to 0.  Also, I discovered that a test for Expense Elements and a nested for-each loop worked just fine in adding Expense elements to the node-set. So many thanks for your help.